# Using different versions of R in RStudio with complete independence

Tags: r, rstudio

I use RStudio for both work projects and study projects. For work, we use version 3.5.3 and there are many inhouse packages that we use, and it is strictly administrated. I need to use newer versions for study, but when I updated R to a newer version, it completely ruined all my work projects and spat out loads of error messages which took my admin team many hours to diagnose and repair. Their solution to the problem is to have me only use on 3.5.3.

Is there a way to have the old and new versions installed but to be able to work in the two versions entirely independent of one another, so that if I download a package or change the settings (for example) in the study environment, it has absolutely no effect on the work environment?

Comment: There will never have complete independence between R and RStudio. For example, the latest RStudio version (1.4.1106) requires R version of 3.0.1 or above, in order to run successfully.
See: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Comment: Yes I know that - but is there a way to use two different versions of R without them disrupting the settings of each other?